# How to read some rows of database, sum on some columns and store in collection?

Tags: database, collections, anylogic

I have an Access file that contains three sheets (each sheet belongs to one customer), and each sheet contains the orders of 9 products for 25 weeks.

I want to store the sum of each of the 3 products for 12 weeks in a collection.

For example:

[order list of customer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8nQR.jpg)

How could I do some operation on the database (like sum on columns) and store them in the collection?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
List <Integer> result=selectFrom(customer1).list(customer1.product1);
double theSum=sum(result,c->c.intValue());
```

Another option:

```
int theSum=(int) selectFirstValue(int.class,"SELECT SUM (product1) FROM customer1;");
```